# MDX Filter Dimension Members Only

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

This is probably quite simple but I have a piece of MDX that filters all my customers, that have a balance over 100. This returns a set of tuples containing the customer and the balance. How do i return just a set of the customers?

```
Filter(
          [Customer].[Customer Name].Children,
          [Measures].[Balance] > 100
     )
```

I intend to use this as the expression for a named set in my cube.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure to understand how you get ( customer, balance ) tuples; anyway, you might be looking at the [extract](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Extract.html) function. It allows you to retrieve the tuples with members of the specified hierarchy: e.g.,

```
Extract( my-set , [Customer].[Customer Name] )
```